# tcp listen on any ip any port with gvisor

Tags: gvisor

How to use the tcpip stack in `gvisor` to implement `tun2socks`?

gvisor.dev/gvisor/pkg/tcpip/stack (https://github.com/google/netstack)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/xjasonlyu/tun2socks is a `tun2socks` implementation built on top of gVisor's netstack which may serve as a good reference, or directly meet your needs.